# horizontal align image and paragraph

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to align my image with a title and a subtitle in a web page. I would like the image to be at the left and the title with its subtitle centered at the middle.

```
 <header>
    <div class="title_div">
        <img src="pictures/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
        <p>
           <h1>Title</h1>
           <h2>Subtitle</h2>
        </p>
     </div>
 </header>
```

I tried to use the float:left attribute but the image goes out from the header... I saw that because I use the following css attributes:

```
header{
    background:#f1f1f1;
    border: black solid;
}
```

I would like to reach something like https://www.ted.com/ but with a subtitle under "Ideas worth spreading".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using separate div for your logo and your text makes it much cleaner:

```
<header>
<div class="logo">
  <img src="pictures/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
</div>

<div class="title_div">
 <h1>Title</h1>
 <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
header{
 float:left;
}

.logo{
 float:left;
 margin:20px;
}
.title_div{
 float:left;
}
```

Note: Just a side note that you have very improper use of HTML. `P` tag is for paragraph, `H1` is for headings, so you cant put heading inside a `P` tag. Re-structure your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to @user45250's but I'm using a vertical alignment technique for mutli-line text in respect to the image.

```html
<header class="cf">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="logo">
     <div class="title">
         <h2>Title</h2>
         <strong>Subtitle</strong>
     </div>
 </header>
```

```css
/* Micro Clearfix - http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
header {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border: black solid;
}
.title {
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img, .title {
    float: left;
}
```

I have used the [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) as `<header>` will collapse as it's child elements have been floated.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4oebfxu8/)

Answer (score 1):

you can easily do this with the table display properties:

*html clean up and valid ...*

```css
header {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;/* or was it just vertical-align ? */
  border:1px solid
  }
header>div {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;/* or was it just text-align ? */
  }
.title_div {
  width:1%;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="title_div">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/&text=logo" alt="logo" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>

  </div>
</header>
```